# Three awk calls in 1

Tags: bash, awk

The following works as expected:

```
awk '$1 <= -700 { print $3 }' FS="," tmp | awk '!seen[$0]++'

23
60
73
91
```

and now I count those four values and print the number 4:

```
awk '$1 <= -700 { print $3 }' FS="," tmp | awk '!seen[$0]++' | awk '{ count++ } END { print count }'

4
```

Is there a shorter way to do these three awk calls in one call?

Hints are much appreciated,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '$1 <= -700 && !seen[$3]++ {c++} END{print c+0}' FS="," tmp
```

Explanation:

```
# If column 1 <= -700 and we've not seen the value of column 3 yet ...
$1 <= -700 && !seen[$3]++ {
   # ... increment the counter c
   c++
}

# When the end of the input file is reached, print the counter
END {
    # Note: incrementing the counter by 0 ensures that c
    # has the value 0 when no line matched the criterias and thereby
    # c has never been incremented. Without this, c would be an
    # empty string. This gets often forgotten. Thanks @Ed Morton!

    # Alternatively you may run the program as awk -v c=0 ...
    print c+0 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Count values? Just put the values in the array and print the length, you do not need to print anything.

```
awk '$1 <= -700 { uniq[$3] } END{ print length(uniq) }'
```

Comment: the `tmp` file is first filtered, then unique values are obtained, and finally awk counts values. Just tried your code and did not do the trick.

Comment: @KamilCuk why you elected to not inform `AWK` that `,` should be treated as field separator?

Comment: @Daweo I hoped it is obvious.